# How to plot cascade view in python using bokeh or matplotlib?

Tags: python, bokeh

[Basically how can I plot the following chart][image: 1]

I'm trying to create an offset between each line plot to produce the same plot in the picture without the lines overlapping on top of each other.

below is my code trying bokeh dodge(), but it doesn't run!:

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import ColorPicker, RangeSlider,HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.transform import dodge

TOOLTIPS = [
    ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
]

p = Figure(
    x_range=(dfs[0]['t'].min(), dfs[0]['t'].max()),
              x_axis_label = "t (ns)",
              y_axis_label = "mV",
            tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
              plot_width=850, 
              plot_height=600

)
for i in range(0,menu):
    line = p.line(x=dfs[i].t,legend_label=file_names[i],
                 y=dodge(dfs[i].A,cascade[i],p.x_range),
                 color=random.choice(color), 
                 line_width=2)
    p.legend.location = "top_left"
    p.legend.click_policy="hide"

    output_file("Test.html", title="Test")
    
    

    range_slider = RangeSlider(
        title=" Adjust X-Axis range",
        start=0,
        end=dfs[0]['t'].max(),
        step=1e-5,
        value=(p.x_range.start, p.x_range.end),
    )
    range_slider.format = "0.000000"
    range_slider.js_link("value", p.x_range, "start", attr_selector=0)
    range_slider.js_link("value", p.x_range, "end", attr_selector=1)

    
    ##Final Chart layout
layout = layout([
#             [picker],
            [range_slider],
            [p]])

p.toolbar.autohide = True

p.title_location = "above"
p.title.text = "Ultrasonic"
p.title.text_font_size = "30px"
p.title.align = "center"
p.title.text_color = "black"

show(layout)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: failed to validate Dodge(id='1207', ...).value: expected a value of type Real, got 0      -0.000937
```

Comment: Your error is in this line: `y=dodge(dfs[i].A,cascade[i],p.x_range)`, you have to pass `dodge(field_name: str, value: float, range: Range | None = None)`. In your case `dfs[i].A` is not a string of `cascade[i]` is not a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to plot the lines:

Let`s assume you have all imports you need and this very simple DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.transform import dodge
output_notebook()

dfs = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[1,2,3]})
>>>
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
```

Than you can calculate a `fixed_offset` for each column.

```
offset = 5
fixed_offset = dfs.max().shift(1).fillna(0).cumsum() + [i*offset for i in range(dfs.shape[1])]
```

Now you have two options:

1. Modify the original data and plot a line

```
dfs = dfs.add(fixed_offset)
source = ColumnDataSource(dfs)
p = Figure(width=300, height=300, x_range=(-1,3))
for name, color in zip(dfs.columns, ['blue', 'green']):
    p.line(
        x='index',
        legend_label=name,
        y=name,
        line_width=2,
        source=source,
        color = color,
    )
show(p)
```

or

2. use dodge:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(dfs)
p = Figure(width=300, height=300, x_range=(-1,3))
for name, value, color in zip(dfs.columns, fixed_offset, ['blue', 'green']):
    p.line(
        x='index',
        legend_label=name,
        y=dodge(name, value),
        line_width=2,
        source=source,
        color = color,
    )
```

In both cases the output is

[image: stacked line plot]